# CABasicAnimation on transform.scale translates CAShapeLayer on the X & Y axis

Tags: swift, cabasicanimation

I am trying to add a pulsating effect around a button, however, the code I am using translates the `CAShapeLayer` as well as increasing its size.

How do I only increase the scale of a `CAShapeLayer` during this animation whilst keeping its position in the view static?

I have isolated the code out into a simple project which performs this animation and it is still occurring.

See effect in a video here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/or3s2.jpg

To test this:

1. Create a new project
2. Add a button into the centre of the view
3. Link it to the viewControllers code file as an IBOutlet with the name `beginButton`

Here is my code:

```
let pulsatingLayer = CAShapeLayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: beginButton.center, radius: beginButton.bounds.midX, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: 2 * .pi, clockwise: true)

    pulsatingLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
    pulsatingLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    pulsatingLayer.lineWidth = 10
    pulsatingLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    pulsatingLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
    view.layer.addSublayer(pulsatingLayer)

    animatePulsatingLayer()
}

private func animatePulsatingLayer() {
    let pulseAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
    pulseAnimation.toValue = 1.5
    pulseAnimation.duration = 1
    pulseAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)
    pulseAnimation.autoreverses = true
    pulseAnimation.repeatCount = Float.infinity
    pulsatingLayer.add(pulseAnimation, forKey: "pulsing")
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you set the bounds/frame of the pulsatingLayer??

Comment: I do not believe I am anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your animation is relative to the origin of the frame of the `view`.

By changing the center of the circular path to be `CGPoint.zero`, you get an animation that pulses centered on the origin of the layer. Then by adding that to a new `pulsatingView` whose origin is centered on the button, the pulsing layer is centered on the button.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint.zero, radius: beginButton.bounds.midX, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: 2 * .pi, clockwise: true)

    pulsatingLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
    pulsatingLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    pulsatingLayer.lineWidth = 10
    pulsatingLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    pulsatingLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound

    let pulsatingView = UIView(frame: .zero)
    view.addSubview(pulsatingView)
    view.bringSubview(toFront: beginButton)

    // use Auto Layout to place the new pulsatingView relative to the button
    pulsatingView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    pulsatingView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: beginButton.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    pulsatingView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: beginButton.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    pulsatingView.layer.addSublayer(pulsatingLayer)
    animatePulsatingLayer()
}
```

Comment: Probably, just setting the `center(X/Y)Anchor` constraints will be enough for that.

Comment: @pacification, the origin (leading, top) of the pulsatingView needs to be aligned to the center of the button.

Comment: @vacawame, hm, can you explain why? i tested your and my (`pulsatingView.center(X/Y)Anchor`) edits and they all work well.

Comment: @pacification Hah! Oh, of course.  Because the view has no width/height, top/leading == centerY/centerX.

Comment: oh, sure! the view has `.zero` frame. nice catch! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on transformation matrixes. (Any book on 3D computer graphics should have a section that covers it.)

A scale transformation is centered on the current origin. So if your shape is not centered on the origin, it will be drawn in **towards** the origin. To scale a shape in toward it's own center you need to do something like this:

Create an identity transform
Translate it by (-x, -y) of your shape's center
Add the desired scale to the transform
Add a Translate by (x, y) to shift the shape back

Concat your transform to the layer's transform.

(I always have to think really hard to get this stuff right. I wrote the above off the top of my head, before 7:00 AM local time on a weekend, without sufficient caffeine. It probably isn't exactly right, but should give you the idea.)

Comment: Thanks for that information, however, this code has been used and worked for others... For instance, following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lYVazkkjOb8 this works correctly and he doesn't seem to do what you're saying? Although, please correct me if I am incorrect here!

Comment: Can you post a video of what you're getting?